# Why is JavaScript modulus (%) operator not working as expected?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small program which takes as input an integer N and returns true if it is a power of 3. Otherwise, false.

While there are many ways to write such a program, I am particularly interested in ** only ** making following solution work.

- First, I find max integer value supported by JavaScript i.e. `Number.MAX_VALUE`
- Then, using this I get max interger value divisible by 3 using formula: `Math.floor(Math.log(Number.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(3))`. This comes out to be `646`.

So far so good.

Now, idea is that if `3^646 mod N == 0`, then N is a power of 3 because 3 is a prime number.

This works perfectly fine on Wolfram Alpha (e.g. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283%5E646%29+mod+27).

**Problem:**

But I don't get zero when I do the same using JavaScript i.e. `Math.pow(3, 646) % 27` returns `5`, instead of `0`.

- Isn't `%` the modulus operator I am suppose to use?
- Am I missing something here?

Thanks :)

Comment: the number is just too big for javascript

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum value *possible to be represented*. But `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the maximum value you can *operate on* without losing precision. And MAX_VALUE > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Check this out for bigint https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint

Comment: @Ctznkane525 interesting info. I tried `BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE) % 27n`. I was expecting it to return 0 but it return `20n`. I thought, may be the least significant `0` is the zero I was expecting but then when I tried `BigInt(Number.MAX_VALUE) % 27n`, it returned `2n`. What is this sorcery - any idea?

Comment: You can always look at the source code for the Js file....it's visible

Answer (score 0):

For correct integer arithmetic the limit is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` not `Number.MAX_VALUE`. The latter is the limit for floating point representations, and is a number with over 300 digits (in decimal representation). But this is irrelevant for integer arithmetic, as the IEEE 754 floating point representations only has the memory to store about 17 significant decimal digits.

So your exercise should be executed as:

```js
const safeExponent = Math.floor(Math.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) / Math.log(3));
console.log("exponent = " + safeExponent);
const power = Math.pow(3, safeExponent);
console.log("power = " + power);
const remainder = power % 27;
console.log("remainder = " + remainder); // 0
```

For larger integers you could switch to `BigInt`, and then there is no more limit, except for the memory that is available. So for example, here is 3<sup>100000</sup> which has over 47,000 digits:

```js
const largeExponent = 100000n;
console.log("BigInt exponent = " + largeExponent);
const largePower = 3n ** largeExponent;
console.log("BigInt power = " + largePower);
console.log("BigInt power number of digits = " + (largePower+'').length);
const remainder = largePower % 27n;
console.log("remainder " + remainder); // 0
```